# Pass by value of a volatile reference type

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, volatile, pass-by-value

I've not seen a questions similar to mine, so I hope I've not missed anything.

I'm curious if the `volatile` property of a field inside a class is kept when passing that field by value (meaning a local copy reference is created that points to the initial object).

The VS warnings pretty much, tell me that passing by reference of a `volatile` field does not keep the volatility of it. But I was wondering if the passing by value does keep the `volatile` property.

Code samples that illustrates the issue:

```
class static Singleton
{
     private static volatile MyObject myObject;
     private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

     public static MyObject My => HandleObject(syncRoot, myObject);

     private void HandleObject(object syncRoot, MyObject myObject)
     {
          if(myObject.SomeProperty) //is the myObject reference still volatile? 
          { /* some other code */ }
     }
}
```

As I said above, my question is whether `myObject` reference copy is still `volatile` inside the `HandleObject` method?

I know that if I change the signature of `HandleObject` to be `void HandleObject(object syncRoot, ref MyObject myObject)` I loose the volatility, since the VS tooltip tells me as much. But I get no warning/notice if I just pass by value.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks, and have a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you apply the `volatile` keyword on a reference data type (i.e. an object), it **only** affects the variable that keeps the reference to the object (like a *pointer* in unmanaged OOP languages), and not what's inside of that object.

So when you pass the *reference variable* by-value to a method, it's content (address to the object) is copied and there's no need to keep the volatility property on the copied value, since it won't affect the actual variable being copied.

On the other hand, if you pass a reference to a reference variable to a method, the method is able to change the actual passed reference, which might break the volatility, as the compiler warns you.

Take a look at the following code for better understanding.

```
class SomeClass {
    private volatile Object myObject = new Object();

    private void HandleObject(Object theObject) {
        // The `theObject` argument is a copy of the passed variable
        // and the following line won't change the actual variable's
        // value, but the local instance.
        theObject = new Object();
    }

    private void HandleObjectRef(ref Object theObject) {
        // The actual variable's value will be changed, when the
        // following line is executed.
        theObject = new Object();
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        // This call is safe, the `myObject` variable won't be
        // changed after when `HandleObject` is executed.
        this.HandleObject(myObject);

        // The `myObject` will be changed after when `HandleObjectRef`
        // is executed. (WARNING)
        this.HandleObjectRef(ref myObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so then it's a definite that copy by value loses the volatility property? Meaning if I want to use volatile in a multi-threaded singleton scenario I can't use the copy of the reference when reading from it, as it won't be safe anymore (since it's no longer volatile and I may read stale data)? So does this mean that volatility is lose in both copy scenarios? And I have to work with the original reference in order to benefit from it?

Comment: And if the volatility does not transfer over to a copy of the reference when doing pass by value, why does the compiler not warn about this, like it does for the pass by reference?

Comment: Copying a `volatile` variable does not affect the original variable, i.e. the original variable remains `volatile` and volatility is not broken/lost; and that's obvious, since altering the copy won't affect the original variable.

Comment: Here's a good explanation you can read: [When to use the volatile keyword in C#](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3229360/c-sharp/how-to-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-c.html)

Comment: Yes. the original does not lose volatility. I understood that. But the copy is not volatile right? That was what my initial wondering. If the local-method reference that points to the same object is also volatile. And from what you're saying, it is not volatile. Thanks for the link.